Bind C-h in tmux copy mode
I'm trying to bind C-h to move to the window on the left. Here is my tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
bind -n S-down new-window
bind -n C-l next
bind -n C-h prev
bind q killp
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-space
bind-key C-a send-prefix
bind c new-window -a
set-option -g history-limit 20000
set -g pane-border-style 'fg=colour1'

All of these bindings work as expected in normal mode. In copy mode, they all work except C-h, which still functions as backspace and just moves the cursor left. I'm using Vi global bindings so I guess that's why. Is is possible to overwrite this Vi binding?
I've tried adding unbind-key C-h first, makes no difference.
The output of tmux list-keys -T copy-mode-vi | grep cursor-left is:
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h send-keys -X cursor-left
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi h send-keys -X cursor-left
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi BSpace send-keys -X cursor-left
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Left send-keys -X cursor-left


This tmux command:
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h

will remove whatever is bound to C-h in copy-mode-vi. In your case the binding to remove is the default one:

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h send-keys -X cursor-left


Now your new bind -n C-h prev (whose full form is bind-key -T root C-h previous-window) should work also in copy mode, when mode-keys is set to vi.
You will probably want to put our unbind-key … into your ~/.tmux.conf. Keep in mind the file is parsed when a tmux server starts. To affect your already running server you need to pass the command to tmux by hand (e.g. tmux unbind-key … in a shell inside tmux) or to reload the altered file (e.g. prefix:source-file ~/.tmux.confEnter).

Great thanks. I first thought you meant I should put unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h in tmux.conf, but that didn't do anything. However, if I run tmux unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h, it works. Is that normal? Note, it needed to be preceded by tmux to work like that in the terminal.

@ludog Yes, in tmux.conf; but this file is parsed automatically only when a tmux server starts, changing the file does not change the configuration of the already running tmux server.

Hey, yes I know I have to restart for tmux.conf to take effect again, but adding unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h doesn't do anything even when I restart. In fact, running tmux unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-h in the terminal is persistent across tmux restarts.

@ludog "… is persistent across tmux restarts." – I suspect you're confusing tmux client(s) with the tmux server.

Ah yes, you're right, I was confusing those things. I had restarted the tmux session but there was another session still running in another terminal tab so the server did not restart. Exiting all sessions and then relaunching makes the changes take effect.
